# How do I translate a foreach c# 2d array loop to java

Tags: java, c#, arrays

I have this piece of C# code that I need to re-write in java.

```
private static void ShowGrid(CellCondition[,] currentCondition)
{

        int x = 0;
        int rowLength =5;

        foreach (var condition in currentCondition)
        {
            var output = condition == CellCondition.Alive ? "O" : "·";
            Console.Write(output);
            x++;
           if (x >= rowLength)
            {
                x = 0;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
}
```

So far my java code looks like this:

```
private static void ShowGrid(CellCondition[][] currentCondition) {

        int x = 0;
        int rowLength = 5;

        for(int i=0;i<currentCondition.length;i++){
            for(int j =0; j<currentCondition[0].length;j++){
                CellCondition[][] condition = currentCondition[i][j];
                //I am stuck at here
                x++;
            if(x>=rowLength){
               x=0; 
               System.out.println();
               }
            }
        }
}
```

I am stuck at after `CellCondition[][] condition = currentCondition[i][j];`line and I am not sure if the looping was done correctly either. Any advise would be grateful.

Comment: `String output = currentCondition[i][j] == CellCondition.Alive ? "O" : "·"; System.out.print(output);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static void ShowGrid(CellCondition[][] currentCondition) {
    int x = 0;
    int rowLength = 5;

    for(int i = 0; i < currentCondition.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < currentCondition[0].length; j++) {
            CellCondition condition = currentCondition[i][j];
            String output = (condition == CellCondition.Alive ? "O" : "·");
            System.out.print(output);
            x++;
            if(x >= rowLength) {
               x = 0; 
               System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just access the cell. Each cell is a `CellCondition`, not a `CellCondition[][]`.

Answer (score 2):

In your case it seems like you're not really interested in knowing what the index is for each of the CellCondition objects. Therefore you couldve used the java equivalent of a foreach loop:

```
for (CellCondition[] a : currentCondition)
{
    for (CellCondition b : a)
    {
        //Do whatever with b
    }
}
```

Comment: thats the better solution.